# Project isn't building on run; I have to build manually before running

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, console-application

Somewhere along the line, something changed with my console project that prevents it from building automatically when I run it.  If I make code changes and then run it without building manually, I get this:

```
Program.cs not found

Locating source for 'F:\pathtoproject\Program.cs'. Checksum: SHA1 {a hash here}
The file 'F:\pathtoproject\Program.cs' exists.
```

However, if I build manually before running, it's fine.

I don't know what setting got changed to cause this.  I also don't use source control, so I can't view older versions of the project file.  Just need to know what happened so I can get it back to normal.

Comment: I don't know whether it would help, but check: `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run`. Make sure `On Run, when projects are of outdate` set to `Always build` and `On Run, when build or deployment  error occurs` set to `Do not launch`.

Comment: @JohnyL Both of those are checked. I actually have mine set to `Prompt to launch`, but same thing.  My other solutions/projects don't exhibit the behavior mentioned with the one in question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the solution and choose Configuration Manager, and select the project to build when the solution is built.

Comment: I don't see such an option in this section.  I just see the Debug/Release configurations and all projects are checked in the Build column

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Yes, I'm referring to checking the project in the Build column. As you have all projects checked, in your case it seems to be a different cause. I would try restarting Visual Studio if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Oops, you're right!  I was looking at the wrong project.  For some reason, my main project was not set to build.  I set it to build and now it's working.  Still, don't know how that happened, but you got me where I needed to be.